# how to find if M is actually an output of 2power(2n) + 1 in C program

Tags: c, embedded

I have a tricky requirement in project asking to write function which returns a value 1 (0 otherwise) if given an integer representable as *2<sup>2n</sup>+1*. Where *n* is any non-negative integer.

```
int find_pow_2n_1(int M);
```

for e.g: return 1, when M=5 since 5 is output when n=1 -> 2<sup>1*2</sup>+1 .

I am trying to evaluate the equation but it results in log function, not able to find any kind of hint while browsing in google as well .

Comment: Think of the binary representation. A number 2^n consists of a single 1-bit followed by 0-bits. 2^2n has an even number of 0-bits. Except for the case n=0 resulting in 2^0+1 = 2, adding 1 will replace the last 0 bit with a 1, resulting in a binary that consists of a 1-bit followed by an odd number of 0-bits and a final 1-bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution

```
int find_pow_2n_1(int M)
{
    return 1 < M && !(M-1 & M-2) && M % 3;
}
```

### Explanation

First, we discard values less than two, as we know the first matching number is two.

Then `M-1 & M-2` tests whether there is more than one bit set in `M-1`:

- `M-1` cannot have zero bits set, since `M` is greater than one, so `M-1` is not zero.
- If `M-1` has one bit set, then that bit is zero in `M-2` and all lower bits are set, so `M-1` and `M-2` have no set bits in common, so `M-1 & M-2` is zero.
- If `M-1` has more than one bit set, then `M-2` has the lowest set bit cleared, but higher set bits remain set. So `M-1` and `M-2` have set bits in common, so `M-1 & M-2` is non-zero.

So, if the test `!(M-1 & M-2)` passes, we know `M-1` is a power of two. So `M` is one more than a power of two.

Our remaining concern is whether that is an even power of two. We can see that when `M` is an even power of two plus one, its remainder modulo three is two, whereas when `M` is an odd power of two plus one, its remainder modulo three is zero:

- Remainder of 2<sup>0</sup>+1 = 2 modulo 3 is 2.
- Remainder of 2<sup>1</sup>+1 = 3 modulo 3 is 0.
- Remainder of 2<sup>2</sup>+1 = 5 modulo 3 is 2.
- Remainder of 2<sup>3</sup>+1 = 9 modulo 3 is 0.
- Remainder of 2<sup>4</sup>+1 = 17 modulo 3 is 2.
- Remainder of 2<sup>5</sup>+1 = 33 modulo 3 is 0.
- …

Therefore, `M % 3`, which tests whether the remainder of `M` modulo three is non-zero, tests whether `M-1` is an even power of two.

Comment: Thanks @Eric this works with maximum cases I verified .

Comment: My gosh, you may do it without division.

Answer (score 2):

There are only a few numbers with that property: make a table lookup array :-)

```
$ bc
for(n=0;n<33;n++)2^(2*n)+1
2
5
17
65
257
1025
4097
16385
65537
262145
1048577
4194305
16777217
67108865
268435457
1073741825
4294967297
17179869185
68719476737
274877906945
1099511627777
4398046511105
17592186044417
70368744177665
281474976710657
1125899906842625
4503599627370497
18014398509481985
72057594037927937
288230376151711745
1152921504606846977
4611686018427387905
18446744073709551617
```

Last number above is `2^64 + 1`, probably will not fit an `int` in your implementation.

Comment: even there are chances of n being higher correct?

Comment: Yes, but your prototype has `int` for `M`: `int find_pow_2n_1(int M);`

Comment: @Harish: If the parameter to the function `find_pow_2n_1` is `int M`, then it can only have `int` values; it can never have a value greater than the maximum value representable in an `int`. If you want your program to be able to test higher values, you need to use some other method. You should update the question to specifically state what sort of input there will be—is the function just passed an `int`, and that is enough, or does it have to read an integer of arbitrary size from input, or what?

Comment: thanks for the answer @pmg  I have tried it but short of memory to store an LUT.

Comment: You only need 32 `int`s for a LUT (lookup table), if you're short of memory you are very constrained indeed. Use one of the other proposed solutions.

Comment: Curiously, these all end with 5 or 7 except the special case 2. Might be possible do some mini-optimization based on that.

Comment: @Lundin, it's called bit operations, or bit twiddling. See my answer.

Comment: for some readers it might be interesting to know what 'bc' is: https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc (An arbitrary precision calculator language)

Answer (score 2):

All proposed solutions are way too complicated or bad in performance. Try the simpler one:

```c
static int is_power_of_2(unsigned long n)
{
  return (n != 0 && ((n & (n - 1)) == 0));
}

static int is_power_of_2n(unsigned long n)
{
  return is_power_of_2(n) && (__builtin_ffsl(n) & 1);
}

int main(void)
{
  int x;

  for (x = -3; x < 20; x++)
    printf("Is %d = 2^2n + 1? %s\n", x, is_power_of_2n(x - 1) ? "Yes" : "no");
  return 0;
}
```

Implementing `__builtin_ffsl()`, if you are using ancient compiler, I leave it as a homework (it can be done without tables or divisions).

Example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/gMrzZqhuP4onF8ku

While commenting on @Lundin's comment I realized that you may read a very nice set of [bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html) from Standford University.

UPDATE. As [@grenix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2623045/grenix) noticed the initial question was about the direct check, it may be done with the above code by introducing an additional wrapper, so nothing basically changes:

```c
...

static int is_power_of_2n_plus_1(unsigned long n)
{
  return is_power_of_2n(n - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
  int x;

  for (x = -3; x < 20; x++)
    printf("Is %d = 2^2n + 1? %s\n", x, is_power_of_2n_plus_1(x) ? "Yes" : "no");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: good idea to test if (x -1) is power of two, although leaving the operation (x-1) to the caller was not the original question

Comment: What about -2147483647 (0x80000001)? This is a negative number (2s complement) and therefore can not be power of 2 + 1.

Comment: @grenix, updated according to the first comment. I don't see the issue with the  `-2147483647`. It's not a `2^(2 * n) + 1`, or I'm missing something?

Comment: It's not because I really checked if your algorithm would answer the question if 0x80000000 is a power of 2 in the right way. I was just wondering because as unsigned data type it is a power of 2 but not as signed.

Comment: @grenix, the trick is in the types, we got an _int_, but convert it to _unsigned long_. Perhaps on 32-bit machines it won't work that way. But then, if you are really strict about negative to be negative, the `if (x < 0) printf("... no\n" , x) else ...` will do it for you. I simply consider a bit silly to discuss this obvious stuff :-) That's why I consider numbers always to be unsigned in the given question.

Answer (score -1):

Here I am leaving you a pseudocode (or a code that I haven't tested) which I think could help you think of the way to handle your problem :)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define EPSILON 0.000001


int find_pow_2n_1(int M) {
    M--;   // M = pow 2n now
    double val = log2(M);    // gives us 2n
    val /= 2;    // now we have n
    if((val * 10) / 10 - val) <= EPSILON) return 1;   // check whether n is an integer or not
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: (a) There is a `log2` function the C standard library. (b) `abs` is an integer absolute value declared in `<stdlib.h>`. Did you mean `fabs`? (c) `int(n)` is C++, not C. (d) No `n` is defined. (e) `#define EPSILON = 0.000001` should not have `=`.

Comment: Thanks for information, I'll edit that part :)

Comment: For b,c,d&e, that was why I said *not tested pseudocode* but not exact answer :)